# UWP Xbox One: Saving and loading data

Tags: javascript, uwp, construct-2, xbox-one

A while back I got my hands on the UWP platform, specifically developing for Xbox One (or Windows 10 with a controller): it's worth noting that I am using [Construct 2](https://www.scirra.com/) to develop my app, so small snippets of JS would be easier to use than big chunks. I was looking for a way to save and load data (maybe in files) to and from the Xbox's storage and I would quite like a way to store locally on the Xbox's hard drive, although if this isn't possible I can use a cloud based system. I wasn't sure about whether I should be looking at a proper api or maybe just using cookies.

I have looked around the UWP js reference, and I can't seem to find a way of doing this that isn't just writing to files on the computer in Windows 10. Does anyone know anything that could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you are trying to store there are a few ways to do this in UWP apps.

Take a look at the `ApplicationData.Current` class. It exposed properties for local files or settings and roaming files or settings.

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MySettingsKey"] = value;
```

Comment: Sir, I have updated the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100306/j3k0-cordova-plugin-purchase-sandbox-mode-not-working) pl. have a look at it.