# J3k0 cordova-plugin-purchase sandbox mode not working?

Tags: cordova, in-app-purchase

Well, I'm almost done with Cordova in-app purchasing to get it work in windows sandbox mode. I have gone through [this](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/294) thread and tried in all possible way to make it but I couldn't. I have placed `in-app-purchase.xml` in `www` folder as per the instruction. Code follows.

```
 store.verbosity = store.QUIET;
 store.sandbox=true;

                store.register({
                    id: productId,
                    type: store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION
                });

                // Listen to the 'updated' event for individual product
                store.when(productId).updated(function (p) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                });

                // Initiate a purchase
                store.order(productId);

                // When the purchase is approved, show an alert
                store.when(productId).approved(function (order) {
                    Store.subscribeWindows(month, order);
                    order.finish();
                });

                // When the purchase is approved, show an alert
                store.when(productId).cancelled(function (order) {
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Subscribe was cancelled!',
                        template: 'Try again!'
                    });
                    order.finish();
                });

                // When the store is ready all products are loaded and in their "final" state.
                store.ready(function () {
                    console.log("The store is ready");
                });

                // Deal with errors:
                store.error(function (err) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Something went wrong',
                        template: err.message
                    });
                })


                // This will contact the server to check all registered products validity and ownership status.
                // It's mostly fine to do this only at application startup but you can refresh it more often.
                store.refresh();

            }
```

**in-app-purchase.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CurrentApp>
  <ListingInformation>
    <App>
      <AppId>CN=CB5BB00C-6A35-44A7-B46E-013721E959BD</AppId>
      <LinkUri>https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh3tvsk</LinkUri>
      <CurrentMarket>en-us</CurrentMarket>
      <AgeRating>12</AgeRating>
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>App Name</Name>
        <Description>App Description</Description>
        <Price>0</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      </MarketData>
    </App>
    <Product ProductId="com.product.premium365" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>com.product.premium365</Name>
        <Price>59.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
    <Product ProductId="Product03" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>Product03</Name>
        <Price>14.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        xmlfile.xml
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
    <Product ProductId="com.product.premium6" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>com.product.premium6</Name>
        <Price>29.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
    <Product ProductId="com.product.premium" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>com.product.premium</Name>
        <Price>4.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
  </ListingInformation>
  <LicenseInformation>
    <App>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
    </App>
    <!-- Setting a prepurchased durable -->
    <Product ProductId="com.product.premium365">
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
    </Product>
  </LicenseInformation>
</CurrentApp>
```

And the screen shot below is my nightmare - Error.

[image]

I had tried `store.inappbilling.setTestMode();` but it's logging the error

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'setTestMode'
```

**Resources used**

- [In-app-purchase plugin](https://github.com/rafaellop/cordova-plugin-purchase) (From [rafaellop](https://github.com/rafaellop) repo forked from J3k0)
- windows edge simulator for testing

I also tried [dkarzon](https://github.com/dkarzon/cordova-plugin-purchase) forks that as well doesn't work for me.

> I'm about to reach the dead end of the tasks. Pl. someone helps
>   me out. It' vital.

**Update -> 1**

As per **dkarzon's** instruction I have used the library from main repo and registered `store.inappbilling.setTestMode()` with callback and it triggers the failure call back. It's giving an error `missing command error` when I declared function [error call back](https://pastebin.com/Qjb2QezX) with arg. Pl. note that I'm directly testing the app, not from the store. Here is the [code snippet](https://pastebin.com/UuRigSfN) I used to do. Now, It skips the sandbox mode and showing the windows purchase dialog with selected `add-ons` directly likewise in production.

**Update -> 2**

I debugged and figured out that the `folder.getFileAsync("in-app-purchase.xml")` failing to executes and returns an error initially `Input data not in expected format` then I have edited the file by following the structure of [WindowsStoreProxy.xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials-using-the-windows-applicationmodel-store-namespace#proxy), now it's giving an error `The parameter is incorrect`.

[image]

> Here is my updated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<CurrentApp>
  <ListingInformation>
    <App>
      <AppId>CN=CB5BB00C-6A35-44A7-B46E-013721E959BD</AppId>
      <LinkUri>https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh3tvsk</LinkUri>
      <CurrentMarket>en-us</CurrentMarket>
      <AgeRating>12</AgeRating>
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>App Name</Name>
        <Description>App Decription</Description>
        <Price>0.00</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
      </MarketData>
    </App>
    <Product ProductId="com.product.premium" LicenseDuration="10" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>com.product.premium</Name>
        <Price>4.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
    <Product ProductId="Product03" LicenseDuration="0" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>Product03</Name>
        <Price>14.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
  </ListingInformation>
  <LicenseInformation>
    <App>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
    </App>
    <Product ProductId="com.product.premium">
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <ExpirationDate>2018-01-19T00:00:00.00Z</ExpirationDate>
    </Product>
  </LicenseInformation>
</CurrentApp>
```

**Update -> 3**

My bad, After a deep debug I found that I've given Package Identity instead of `AppId` in XML and that cause to the issue and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42436688/4817630) also helped me out. Generated app id using `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId` and hence I'm able to see the purchase simulate pop up. all the error code is triggering callbacks but when I select `S_OK` it returns nothing. I have gone through this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33958869/4817630) but it doesn't work, unfortunately.

[image]

> Updated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<CurrentApp>
  <ListingInformation>
    <App>
      <AppId>fb9ec87b-54b-46f-b1e6-87d857dfa730</AppId>
      <LinkUri>http://apps.windows.microsoft.com/app/988b90e4-5d4d-4dea-99d0-e423e414fbc</LinkUri>
      <CurrentMarket>en-us</CurrentMarket>
      <AgeRating>12</AgeRating>
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>App Name</Name>
        <Description>App Description</Description>
        <Price>0.00</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
      </MarketData>
    </App>
    <Product ProductId="com.product.premium" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>com.product.premium</Name>
        <Price>4.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
    <Product ProductId="Product03" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>Product03</Name>
        <Price>14.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
    <Product ProductId="com.product.premium6" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>com.product.premium6</Name>
        <Price>29.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
    <Product ProductId="com.product.premium365" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>com.product.premium365</Name>
        <Price>59.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>

  </ListingInformation>
  <LicenseInformation>
    <App>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
    </App>
  </LicenseInformation>

</CurrentApp>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the plugin from the main repo instead of a fork? Windows fixed have been merged into master last I checked. `setTestMode` doesn't exist on that branch you are looking at.

Comment: Thanks for your kind consideration **@dkarzon**. Yes, I have tried the latest [version(6.1.2)](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) from the main repo of  `j3k0` and enabled sandbox mode using `store.inappbilling.setTestMode()` with callback and it triggers the failure call back. pl. note that I'm directly testing the app, not from the store. Here is the [code snippet](https://pastebin.com/UuRigSfN) I used to do.

Comment: It skips the sandbox mode and showing the windows purchase dialog with selected `add-ons` directly likewise in production.

Comment: It's giving an error `missing command error` when I declared function [error call back](https://pastebin.com/Qjb2QezX) with arg.

Comment: What do you mean by `windows edge simulator for testing`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I mean I used windows 10 desktop application/Local device for testing the app.

Comment: It's throwing the same error `missing command error` when testing in windows mobile simulator as well. when using `store.sandbox = true` as mentioned in the main repo [Documentation for Windows](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/master/doc/windows.md)  it says `Init failed - undefined` :(

Comment: Are you able to debug the plugin js to see at what point it fails?

Comment: It's breaking here `return cordova.exec(success, errorCb(fail), "InAppBillingPlugin", "setTestMode", [""]);` . there is no command  `setTestMode`.

Comment: Ok, you need to set `store.sandbox = true;` to tell it to use the simulator instead of anything else you are trying to do.
Make that call before your call to `store.refresh` and it will set it up for you.
Then debug `InAppPurchaseProxy.js` to see what is failing in there. You also need to use the real package not one of the branches since this has changed a few times.

Comment: Yes, I have made the call to `store.sandbox=true` before `store.refresh` as you can see code snippet in the query. and I have cloned https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase.git to ensure I'm in the latest revision. Even though I'm triggering `store.sandbox=true` it fails to find out the native method `init` at the line `cordova.exec(success, errorCb(fail), "InAppBillingPlugin", "init", [skus]);`. BTW, Let me debug it if you have any further idea on this pl. let me know. Thank u.

Comment: Pl. see the update in query *@dkarzon*

Comment: `approved` call back is not triggering.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, things are working fine now I got the `approved` callback. thanks to all for the support especially to [@dkarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75946/dkarzon) who find time in b/w busy life.

*I added one of the product as active under `LicenseInformation` tag as well. **Update -> 3** in the query has the other step to get rid of these kind of issue, see that as a reference if any one face difficulty to make windows sandbox mode work in future.*

```
<LicenseInformation>
    <App>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
    </App>
    <Product ProductId="com.animecrave.premium">
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
    </Product>
  </LicenseInformation>
```

> References

- [How to Implement In-App Purchases in Windows 10 Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308032/how-to-implement-in-app-purchases-in-windows-10-apps/33958869#33958869)
- [UWP: Cannot access LicenseInformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422150/uwp-cannot-access-licenseinformation/42436688#42436688)
- https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/win10-1507/Samples/Store/shared/data/expiring-product.xml
- https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials-using-the-windows-applicationmodel-store-namespace#proxy
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp
- http://www.wadewegner.com/2012/09/getting-the-application-id-and-hardware-id-in-windows-store-applications/